# S3のフォルダの数を取得したい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, aws, amazon-s3

S3でフォルダの数だけ取得する事ってできますか？

例えば、

```
jazz/chill/chord_01/xxx.wav
jazz/chill/chord_01/xxx.wav
jazz/chill/chord_01/xxx.wav
jazz/chill/chord_02/xxx.wav
jazz/chill/chord_03/xxx.wav
```

という構成の時に、

```
[jazz/chill/chord_01/, jazz/chill/chord_02, jazz/chill/chord_03/].count 
=> 3
```

```

のように、フォルダ数だけ取得したいです。

ファイル数情報は、下記のようなコードで取得できましたが、
フォルダ情報だけの取得方法がわかりません。

```
def get_files(file_path='')
  resp = @s3.list_objects({
    bucket: Settings.aws.bucket_name,
    prefix: file_path
  })
  resp.to_h[:contents]
end
```

お助けいただけると幸いです、よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

ruby 自体のコードは、ぱっとはでてこないので、方針を。

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ListingKeysHierarchy.html

上記ページなどを参照すると、 aws s3 の api には、区切り文字と prefix を指定して list object すると、prefix の次1階層分のデータを取得できそうなのが、読み取れます。

おそらく、今回ですと、 aws-sdk-s3 を利用して、以下の条件で list_objects するのが、いいのではないか、と思っています。(未検証)

```
@s3.list_objects({
    bucket: Settings.aws.bucket_name,
    prefix: 'jazz/chill/',
    delimiter: '/'
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

S3にはフォルダという概念はありませんので、得られたキーをファイル名とみなして `dirname` などでフォルダとして扱いたい部分を取り出し、ユニークな名前を数えることになります。